# LDAP server setup with GUI on CentOS7

Tags: centos, authentication, ldap

I have, in the past, set up an LDAP server using OpenSuSE (13.2), which worked well since there was a YaST module which allowed a GUI set-up.

Now I have the problem that I must set up an OpenLDAP server on a small department cluster running CentOS 7, which apparently does not have a GUI/TUI for such purposes. Since I am not experienced with the LDIF-based set-up and I fully expect that the maintenance of the cluster is going to be dropped on a different PhD student when I'm gone I want to be able to configure the LDAP server using some sort of GUI.

To date I have tried Webmin, which was a total fiasco. It appears to set up the basic configuration of the server OK (at least `slapd` starts), but If I try to run any query against the DB the response is `Search failed: No such object`, even for the base DN.

If I attempt to add a tree (i.e. an organisational unit) using said interface the result is an error stating that Webmin could not find a suitable object class for the new DN. Therefore I'm giving up on this piece of software.

*My question is thus:* Is there a free tool which would allow one to configure an LDAP server in CentOS without having to write the entire configuration by hand?

Here I am looking specifically for tools which are **not** web-based (so not phpLDAPadmin) but come with a GUI/TUI. Something like `authconfig-gtk` in CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://jxplorer.org/ it has for both unix and windows

Comment: I've been using JXplorer to browse and modify the LDAP tree of my department server, but AFAIK it is not suited to setting up a LDAP server from scratch.

Comment: @Nox Try `Apache Directory Studio`